# sending structure via QTcpSocket

Tags: qt

Can we send structure which contains pointers to another structures, via QTcpSocket  socket to QTcpServer socket of a program running at other physical location then this program. My code will be like this....

```
<i>
QTcpSocket tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
Struct a{ int a1; int a2;} __attribute__((packed));

Struct b { int b1; int b2}__attribute__((packed));
Struct c{ a *c1; a*c2; }QByteArray block;

QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out << quint16(0)<<c;
out << quint16(block.size() - sizeof(quint16));
tcpSocket->write(block);
</i>
```

but this have error like:
/TcpClient-build-desktop/../TcpClient/tcpclient.cpp:137: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘out.QDataStream::operator<<(0) << c’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, but it wouldn't make much sense. :-) If the structure has pointers, then those will be invalid on the remote host.

Of course, you could additionally send what the pointers point to, if you need it.

One tip: if you program for portability, remember to convert any integers to network byte order before transferring, and back to host byte order afterwards.

[Wikipedia article about endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: @anjali I've never seen the `attribute((packed))` syntax. Is it some C++ extension?

Comment: _attribute_((packed)) ,tells gcc to leave out all padding between members.

Comment: @anjali OK. That will not help you in this matter. I think you should consider what Dariusz Scharsig suggests, to use serialization. And, then, converting any integers.

Answer (score 2):

You can, as long as the receiver knows that it cannot only have  the pointers dereferenced by the sending process.  That would mean communicating back to the source and awaiting the result.  This process is called 'object broking' and has been implemented in e.g. CORBA, COM+, jre and others.

A pointer is only to be interpreted in a known piece of virtual memory.

Comment: Thank You. you means, after sending the packet of TCP, the sending machine will also send  actual data to whom pointers pointing...?

Comment: @anjali: it might, on request.  The point is: the receiver should regard the 'pointers' as handles to objects it cannot resolve by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what has been said you could also use an approach similar to that of the RPC system which also sends the object those pointers point to but keeps them on the heap and changes the pointers on the recieving machine accordingly, that way you actually get pointers that work.
To accomplish this without error is of course not easy and you should use this approach only if it is impossible to change your concept.

Best regards
D

Comment: Thank You. If  I am getting you right, at the time of sending, actually the stream of actual data will have to be send to whom pointers are pointing?? In QTcpSocket we append any object  like QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);  out << quint16(0) <<ObjectStructureToSend;  out.device()->seek(0);tcpSocket->write(block);  so how to convert in actual data before sending?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You have overwritten the << operator in your `ObjectStructureToSend` and in there you don't send the pointer itself (which is useless since it holds an adress to the sending machines memory) but the serialization of the structure the pointer points to. On the other side, where you deserialise you take this "pointer data", create an object on a heap and set the pointer to this adress.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Qxt which has a RPC mechanism in its Network module. You can connect signals and slots through network and send objects of arbitrary types as arguments. You can get it [here](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home).